# Meaning of earlier in "1 year ago, maybe earlier"

Tags: meaning, sentence

Someone told me this a while ago, but I always remember it cause I couldn't quite understand.

Does the "earlier" in the sentence "1 year ago, maybe earlier." means that it was prior to 1 year ago (meaning it could be even 10 years) or does it mean it's less than 1 year (like 5 months ago)?

Thanks.

Comment: The first. If you want to say less than 1 year ago, that could be "1 year ago, maybe [sooner](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/433633/using-soon-for-past-occurrences)" or "more recently" or "less."

Comment: In either case, _earlier_ and _sooner_ are both comparatives, so the rest of the comparative apparatus is also available. In particular, _earlier_ means _earlier **than**_ some time already mentioned (in this case, _a while ago_).

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone, it feels much more clear to me now! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

*Earlier* means "occurring before [that is, farther in the past than, or less far into the future than] a specified time or event".  So if the specified time is "a year ago", earlier than that can only mean "a time farther in the past than a year ago", whether that ends up being one year and a day, or eleven years, or two centuries.